# APIs for historical Market Cap data US markets

Tags: quantitative-finance

I'm looking for APIs for either

1. historical Market Cap data
2. historical balance sheet data

both quarterly for 10 years.

What I've looked at so far:

1. yahoo finance (not far back enough)
2. Alpha Vintage (no balance sheet or historical market)
3. FMP (only annual balance sheet)
4. EOD (only as far back as 2017)

Anyone have any apis/sources for this? I dont mind paying, but I want to exhaust all my options first. My api call count wont be that high (less than 200/month, no time requirement)

Comment: I am not sure if this service meets your requirements but: https://polygon.io/

Comment: It only has 2 years historical, unfortunately and EOD is the cheaper option if I go with paid.

Comment: This question would probably fit better on [quant.stackexchange.com/](https://quant.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Sharadar is the best source I know of for high-quality, historical fundamental data for US stocks at a reasonable price, with history back to 1998. Their data is integrated with QuantRocket and I can vouch for the quality. You can purchase the data [through QuantRocket](https://www.quantrocket.com/sharadar/) if your use case involves analysis and backtesting, or you can purchase [standalone through Nasdaq Data Link](https://data.nasdaq.com/publishers/SHARADAR).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that API https://rapidapi.com/telescopeanalytics-hl8pcoeL44o/api/telescope-stocks-options-price-charts/. This API provide an access to actual information from stock exchanges worldwide. It supports getting information about emitents and the history of share price changes.

Example:

```
import requests

url = "https://telescope-stocks-options-price-charts.p.rapidapi.com/stocks/AAPL"

querystring = {"modules":"assetProfile,summaryProfile,price"}

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "telescope-stocks-options-price-charts.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```